# in demand curve tax on buyer shouldnt it be movement along the graph?

Tags: macroeconomics, supply-and-demand, taxation, price

**if buyer has the burden of tax it shift the demand curve but tax comes under(according to me) in Price of the good so shouldnt it be movement along the graph**
**this is the reasoning in my reading for shifting**
"buyers now have to pay a tax to the government (as well as the price to the sellers) whenever they buy ice cream. Thus, the tax shifts the demand curve for ice cream."